# How to accept both string or None argument to Boost Python function

Tags: boost-python

It is Pythonic to use `None` as the default for an optional argument.  For example, use `None` as the default of a string argument:

```
def f(str_arg=None):
    if str_arg is None:
        str_arg = get_str_arg_default()
    ...
```

Thus `f()` accepts two types for argument `str_arg`: a string or `None`.

Now, we are implementing this function in C++ using Boost Python.  How do I make Boost Python accept both string and `None` types for an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have the function accept a `boost::python::object`? Then you can check if it is `None` by calling `is_none()`.

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/FAQ#How_can_I_check_returning_Python_value_for_None.3F which gives several suggestions for checking if an object is `None` - e.g. `arg.ptr() == object().ptr()`, `arg.ptr() == Py_None` or `arg.is_none()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have not tried it yet, but your proposal certainly looks solid.